# Razor radio button set variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, radio-button

I have a local variable in my cshtml file that I want to be set depending on what value is selected from two radio buttons. I don't want to add the variable to my view model.

```
@{ var boolValue = true; }
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => boolValue, true, new { @class = "pull-left "})<label class="pull-left">list 1</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => boolValue, false, new { @class = "pull-left"})<label class="pull-left">list 2</label>
</div>
```

`boolValue` after this point is always true, and I am given a warning telling me that *'Expression is always true'*. Should be a simple thing I'm sure, but I really cannot find an example of this being done elsewhere.

Comment: `boolValue` is server side code. You cannot change it based on selecting a radio button unless you send the value back to the server. _I don't want to add the variable to my view model._? That makes no sense at all. The purpose of a view model to to represent what you want in the view!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use hidden field for it.
Please check the example below

```
@{ var boolValue = true; }
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => boolValue);
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => boolValue, "true", new { @class = "pull-left ", onclick = "GetSelectedItem(this);" })<label class="pull-left">list 1</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => boolValue, "false", new { @class = "pull-left", onclick = "GetSelectedItem(this);" })<label class="pull-left">list 2</label>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedItem(s){
        document.getElementById("boolValue").value = s.value;
    }


</script>
```